# Can I Update Golang map Concurrently?

Tags: go, concurrency, thread-safety

Everyone is saying **write/read golang map concurrently is not safe**, but can we just update it but not write new keys?

We know code below would cause `fatal error: concurrent map read and map write`.

```golang
var m = make(map[int]int)

for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    go func() {
        m[i] = i
    }()
}
```

Now I'm wondering if we can update map concurrently as below.

```golang
var m = make(map[int]int)

// init memory structure of map
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    m[i] = 0
}

// just update values for old keys concurrently
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    go func() {
        m[i] = i
    }()
}
```

Can we do that?

Comment: Don't do it, even if it happens to work with the current compiler. The runtime is free to re-arrange maps in memory on any update, independent of whether a new key is inserted or an existing key updated, so what works today may break tomorrow. Maps are not safe for concurrent read-write access, period.

Comment: "can we just update it but not write new keys?" No. Updating an existing key is still a write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we do that?

No, of course not. It just produces a runtime error "fatal error: concurrent map writes" (with literally your code, so you could have tried it yourself).

Just stop fighting the language and trying to be clever: **No** **concurrent** **writes** (not even "clever" ones)!

Comment: OP uses closures incorrectly though. If you pass the index to the goroutine as a parameter, it does not crash: https://play.golang.org/p/2PKUlzAZFod

Comment: But then, both ways described by OP work, so not sure if that proves anything: https://play.golang.org/p/6oPO8a5TOl5